# Excel - How to Sum Cells in the same column if the Above Cell has Specific Text

Tags: excel, text

Fisrt thanks everybody for the help.

Lets say i Have the following sheet

```
(Column B)
  Alex
  4
  Alex
  3
  Bart
  2
  Alex
  3
  Bart
  2

   example
   Alex= 10
   Bart= 4
```

I want it to detect if the cell has "Alex" or "Bart" and if it has, it should SUM the number below, just like the example. How do i achieve this without VBA if possible. I imagine that there will be a formula to detect Bart and other one to detect Alex and sum each of them. Thanks again!

Comment: Write your formula to detect the name; and offset the sum range by one row to sum the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=SUMIF($B$3:$B$11,E3,$B$4:$B$12)
```

where your data table above is in `B3:B12`, and the name to sum is in `E3`

Note the offset by one row between the `range` and `sum_range` arguments.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how this solution works even though the solution is so simple. Good answer! Care to explain?

Comment: @urdearboy There is no requirement that `range` and `sum_range` start in the same row (or even be the same size or shape); but the upper left cell of `sum_range` will correspond to the upper left cell of `range`.  So, in this case, `B3` will be tested and if true, `B4` will be added.  And so on down the list.  Of course, testing `B4` for `Alex` would return `FALSE`.  Since the two ranges don't have to be the same size, one could also just specify `B4` as the `sum_range`, but calculation would take longer.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help. You solved my problem. I only replaced the "E3" and "E4" for "Alex" and "Bart" and it worked Perfect !